# Is there any relation between the projective dimension of $_AM$(i.e.left $A$-module $M$) and the projective dimension of $_{A/I}M$?

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field K. Suppose $M$ is a left $A$ module, $I$ is an ideal of $A$ such that $MI=0$. So $M$ can also be seen as  a left $A/I$ module. My question is that is there any relation between the projective dimension of $_AM$(i.e.left $A$-module $M$) and the projective dimension of $_{A/I}M$?

Comment: Correct me if this is wrong, but I do not think that you will get any nice relations without further assumptions. For example, if you take $I = J(A)$ the Jacobson radical so that $A/I$ is semisimple, then every $A/I$-module is projective, but the projective dimensions of, for example, simple $A$-modules (which are all $A/I$-modules) can be quite different.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch That does leave open the possibility that one could have an inequality of projective dimensions (with the quotient having the smaller dimensions). Not that I know if this is actually the case.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : You are right, I only wanted to point out that the projective dimension as $A/I$-module might not be able to tell us much about the projective dimension as $A$-module. The possibility of an inequality as you suggested remains.